# R's pglm vs Stata's xtpoisson - R returns "Inf" standard errors

Tags: r, stata

I'm running a fixed-effects Poisson regression and get different results in Stata and R. Unfortunately I cannot upload and share the data due to legal restrictions.

My code in R is (formula shortened for illustration):

```
library(pglm)    
pdf <- pdata.frame(data, index=c("id","timevar"))    
model <- pglm(y ~ x1 + x3 + x3_lag + x3_lag2 + season + x4 + x1*x3_lag + x1*x3_lag2+x1*x4,
              data = pdf,
              effect = "individual",
              model = "within",
              family = "poisson")
```

where `season` controls for seasonal effects, `Y` is a count variable and `x3` is a treatment.

`summary(model)` yields this:

```
Maximum Likelihood estimation
Newton-Raphson maximisation, 4 iterations
Return code 2: successive function values within tolerance limit
Log-Likelihood: -47369.66 
19  free parameters
Estimates:
                   Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)
x1            -1.031e-04        Inf       0       1
x3            -1.196e-02        Inf       0       1
x3_lag        -4.783e-02        Inf       0       1
x3_lag2       -5.159e-02        Inf       0       1
season02      -7.038e-02        Inf       0       1
season03       9.323e-02        Inf       0       1
season04       1.257e-01        Inf       0       1
season05       1.427e-01        Inf       0       1
season06      -1.217e-01        Inf       0       1
season07      -1.566e+01        Inf       0       1
season08      -2.095e-01        Inf       0       1
season09      -1.886e-01        Inf       0       1
season10       4.488e-02        Inf       0       1
season11      -9.954e-02        Inf       0       1
season12       8.201e-02        Inf       0       1
x4             6.055e-01        Inf       0       1
x1:x3_lag      1.888e-05        Inf       0       1
x1:x3_lag2     3.529e-05        Inf       0       1
x1:x4          4.948e-04        Inf       0       1
```

In Stata14 I used:

```
xtset id timevar
xtpoisson x1 x3 x3_lag x3_lag2 season x4 x1#x3_lag x1#x3_lag2 x1#x4, fe
```

The results in Stata (see below) yield standard errors and where the standard errors are significant the coefficients are very much the same as in R, so I assume in both cases the same model was calculated. The issue is: why do I get standard errors in Stata but "Inf" in R?

```
Conditional fixed-effects Poisson regression    Number of obs     =    110,233
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =     15,945

                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          2
                                                              avg =        6.9
                                                              max =         13

                                                Wald chi2(19)     =     816.49
Log likelihood  = -47369.663                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y         |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                  x1 |  -.0001031   .0002119    -0.49   0.626    -.0005184    .0003121
                  x3 |  -.0119605   .0058094    -2.06   0.040    -.0233467   -.0005744
              x3_lag |  -.0478287   .0122489    -3.90   0.000    -.0718361   -.0238212
                     |
           x3_lag#x1 |   .0000189   .0000225     0.84   0.401    -.0000252     .000063
                     |
             x3_lag2 |  -.0515859   .0138096    -3.74   0.000    -.0786523   -.0245195
                     |
          x3_lag2#x1 |   .0000353   .0000245     1.44   0.149    -.0000127    .0000833
                     |
              season |
                 02  |  -.0703797   .0211975    -3.32   0.001    -.1119261   -.0288333
                 03  |    .093219   .0233858     3.99   0.000     .0473836    .1390544
                 04  |   .1256642   .0270927     4.64   0.000     .0725635    .1787649
                 05  |   .1426421   .0335767     4.25   0.000     .0768331    .2084512
                 06  |  -.1217462    .046838    -2.60   0.009     -.213547   -.0299454
                 07  |  -18.24382   741.5026    -0.02   0.980    -1471.562    1435.075
                 08  |  -.2095094   .0373193    -5.61   0.000    -.2826539   -.1363649
                 09  |  -.1886333   .0341701    -5.52   0.000    -.2556054   -.1216611
                 10  |    .044879   .0278778     1.61   0.107    -.0097604    .0995184
                 11  |  -.0995352   .0249665    -3.99   0.000    -.1484686   -.0506018
                 12  |   .0819983   .0214643     3.82   0.000      .039929    .1240675
                     |
                  x4 |   .6055111   .0754535     8.02   0.000      .457625    .7533972
                     |
               x4#x1 |   .0004948   .0001416     3.49   0.000     .0002173    .0007723
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you have any suggestions on how I could provide a replicable example (maybe with some sample panel data, any suggestions?), I will gladly do so.

**EDIT**

A smaller model produces identical results in R and Stata. It seems that with poor models R is more restrictive and does not show standard errors.

Comment: I can't see this as a programming problem, as you have code and are not asking for programming advice. It's more of a statistical question of why a model fit is produced in one program but not another. Achieving a good fit in one program and not another is often a sign of a fragile model as much as, if not more than, a comment on the software. Although it often attracts flak, my suggestion is to try fitting a simpler model in R: the Stata results suggest which predictors may be omitted. As you realise the lack of a reproducible example constrains comment.

Comment: Voting for migration to Cross Validated.

Comment: You are right, simpler models do not produce this problem.

Comment: As I don't think I will get any help with my model fit without uploading the data, I will mark this post as answered - even though the exact reasons for the disparity remain unclear. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know `pglm` in R at all, or indeed anything much else in R, but I wouldn't be surprised to learn that it has handles to tune the fitting process in difficult cases.

Comment: The issue here seems to be 'pglm' which is not as complex as a regression package could be (also only version 0.1-2 so far), it also doesn't have all the usual features of regression packages. It seems to me that the best way to fit this kind of model is to 'glm' and programm the proper adjustments. I will try to figure that out.

Comment: Have you looked into the source code to see how the Hessian is calculated? If I had to guess, either some elements of the variance-covariance matrix are `0 / NA / NaN`, or there is some reweighting going on, for instance with individual hat-values. Are there any with values equal to 1?

Comment: It may also be a good idea to try different optimization methods. Supply one of the methods from `?maxLik` and see what happens.

Comment: The `R` code issued a warning ("Return Code 2") that should be heeded: it did not actually find a solution.  Until you can develop a reproducible example, I doubt we can do any more about the problem here on CV than they could on SO.  However, you could inspect the variance-covariance matrix produced by the model in `R`: that could be revealing.

Comment: One potential cause could be the use of time invariant variables in a "within" model.

Comment: @gopikumar Perhaps, especially with an indeterminate number of units observed over a couple of time periods. Nonetheless, it's hard to tell for sure without a preview of the OP's data. I am puzzled by the length of the time dimension. I am not sure if the model can handle a 12-level 'seasonal' variable in this highly unbalanced setting. I would recommend dropping the seasonal variables and lags to reduce the complexity, which appears to be inline with Nick Cox's suggestions.